# CSV output from web scrawling using scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-crawler, scrapy

I am saving the output of web scrawling using scrapy in a csv file. The crawling itself seems to be working correctly, but I am not happy with the format of the output saved in csv file. I crawl 20 webpages where each page contains 100 job titles and their respective urls. So I am expecting the output looking like this:

```
url1, title1
url2, title2
...
...
url1999, title1999
url2000, title2000
```

however, the actual output in csv looks like this:

```
url1 url2 ... url100, title1 title2 ... title100
url101 url02 ... url200, title101 title102 ... title200
...
url1901 url902 ... url2000, title1901 title1902 ... title2000
```

My Spider code is:

```
import scrapy

class TextPostItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "craig_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo"]

    def parse(self, response):
        number = 0
        for page in range(0, 20):
            yield scrapy.Request("http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo?=%s" % number, callback=self.parse_item, dont_filter=True)
            number += 100

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = TextPostItem()
        item['title'] =response.xpath("//span[@class='pl']/a/text()").extract()
        item['link'] = response.xpath("//span[@class='pl']/a/@href").extract()
        return item
```

My csv code is:

```
scrapy crawl craig_spider -o craig.csv -t csv
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What is your `csv` code?

Comment: My csv code is:    scrapy crawl craig_spider -o craig.csv -t csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you get a response with multiple `//span[@class='pl']/a/` fields back, loading every `text()` into a list and assigning that to `item['title']`, and then loading every `@href` into a list and assigning that to `item['link']`.

In otherwords for the first response, you are essentially doing the following:

```
item['title'] = [title1, title2, ..., title100]
item['link'] = [url1, url2, ..., url100]
```

So, that's being sent to CSV as:

```
title,link
[title1, title2, ..., title100],[url1, url2, ..., url100]
```

To fix this, loop through each `//span[@class='pl']/a/` and have individual items for each.

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    for span in response.xpath("//span[@class='pl']/a"):
        item = TextPostItem()
        item['title'] = span.xpath(".//text()").extract()
        item['link'] = span.xpath(".//@href").extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Appreciated!